# Scope in JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've clearly been writing too much CoffeeScript, as I am now realizing I do not have even a basic understanding of scope in pure JS.

After playing for a while, I cannot figure out the problem with the following--

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myUrl = "http://notimportant.com/"
    var photos = getPhotos(myUrl);
    console.log(photos);                        //undefined
});

function getPhotos(url) {
    var a;
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        a = data["photoset"]["photo"];
        console.log(a);                        //my object
    });
    return a;
}
```

If I put a console.log(a) statement on the line right below 'var a = data["photoset"]["photo"];' it shows that it properly makes the GET request I'm looking for.  But I'm finding it impossible to pass that object back to my main block of code, where I want to manipulate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$.get` is asynchronous. The statement `return a;` is returned immediately (which is why you're seeing `undefined` in your console) after your `get` call is made. The second argument in get, `function(data)` is your callback which is executed when the ajax response comes back (with the proper data, which you see in your console). To manipulate the data, you could call a function from your `get` callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `photos` is undefined is not because of scopes. Its because `$.get` is executed asynchronously. `$.get()` returns jqXHR object instead of an HTTP response.

`onSuccess` callback should be passed to `getPhotos()` in order to make it work correctly. Alternatively `when().then()` construct could be used.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myUrl = "http://example.com/";
    getPhotos(myUrl, renderCatPhotos);    
});

function getPhotos(url, onSuccess) {
    $.get(url, onSuccess);
}

function renderCatPhotos(data) {
    var a = data.photoset.photo;
    console.log(a);  // a is always available
}
```

*note: you might not even need `getPhotos` function. You can simply `$.get(url, onSuccess);` in `$(document).ready()`* instead.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this up, Jev.  I noticed the console.log's were printing out in unexpected order.  At least glad to know I'm not going crazy re: scopes.  Appreciate you taking the time to write this up!

Answer (score 0):

Its not a matter of scope, its a matter of that you are returning an undefined variable before the $.get defines it.  Consider making photos a global, then setting it in the $.get success function instead of setting it to 'a'.  Inside the success function, you can then issue calls to other functions that would control displaying/processing the photos.

Comment: Thank you, Vizkos.  This is exactly right.  Glad to know I'm not going crazy re: scopes.  Appreciate you pointing me in the right direction.